# Editind image (JLabel) inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, image, swing, jscrollpane

I am developing an image editor capable of drawing ovals on an image. I am able to successfully add an image into a JScrollPane and draw on it using the fillOval() function. But each and every time I move the scroll bar all the drawn ovals disappear. Since the image to be uploaded is often large in size scroll bars cannot be disabled. I have incorporated the image in a JLabel. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to successfully add an image into a JScrollPane and draw on it using the fillOval() function. But each and every time I move the scroll bar all the drawn ovals disappear.

This suggests to me that you're not drawing correctly. Since you've not shown us how you're drawing, we can only guess, but perhaps you're calling `getGraphics()` on a component and using an unstable Graphics instance. If so, you'll be better off calling `getGraphics()` on a BufferedImage itself, and drawing on it. Either that or drawing in the paintComponent method of your JComponent.

If this doesn't help, please provide more information on exactly what you're doing, preferably by creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.